# Can pseudo classes (::after) be added as a part of HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a tooltip on hover. Below is the html/css code for handling the tip (arrow) of the tooltip. I'm using a psedo element `::after` to add styling to the arrow

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip">Hello on hover me</div>
```

css:

```
.tool-tip::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 100%;
  **left: 50%;** // I want to have this value based on some condition, i.e if number is positive => 50%, else 0%;
  border-color: toolTipBGColor transparent transparent;
}
```

As mentioned above I want to have one css property defined in the pseudo class to be condition based, hence I do not want that as a aprt of css and I want to have it as a part of html template so that I can add necessary condition and populate the correct value.
something on the lines of adding inline style, just this will be a pseudo class.

IS this even possible or is there another way to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: You can try [attr](http://go/mdn/CSS/attr). Not sure if that'll work for you.

Comment: use CSS variable like I have described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333 (section *1) Using inline style:*)

Comment: What is the condition???

Comment: @epascarello: I'm checking for a positive / negative integer. ```Math.sign(-1)```, if -1 then I want to ```left: 0%``` , if return 0 , then ```left: 50%```

Comment: if you only have two values, simply define two classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access pseudo-elements through JS or style attribute.

```css
/* the only thing you can do is: */

.tool-tip::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border-color: toolTipBGColor transparent transparent;
}

.tool-tip.modifier::after {
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- And now you can add or remove a .modifier class -->

<div class="tooltip modifier">Hello on hover me</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can specify it in css in some additional class like:

```
.activated::after{
   ....
}
```

Then depending on condition add or remove class.

```
if(condition) {
    element.classList.add('activated');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually access the `::after` through JS, but you could achieve this dynamic result adding another element, let's call *arrow*, and editing it's style inline, like so:

```css
.tootlip {
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 100%;
  border-color: red transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="tootlip">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
</div>
```

This way you can change the arrow style in JavaScript to whatever you want.